# How does Rails create_table work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is more of a `Ruby` question than `Rails`.

**Function signature:**

```
def create_table(table_name, comment: nil, **options)
  ...
end
```

**Usage:**

```
create_table(:suppliers) do |t|
  t.string :name, limit: 60
  # Other fields here
end
```

Given the function signature of `create_table`, how does the usage map to it?

For instance, the
`:suppliers` maps to the `table_name`, how does the `block` map to the function signature?

I also understand that `*` is a splat that accepts `x` number of arguments.
`**` is a double splat (I think), that accepts `x` number of hash (ie. key, value pairs).

So I'm not sure if `**options` has anything to do with the passing of `block`.

ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table

Comment: JFYI, you can pass blocks to ANY ruby method. It is that method's responsibility then either to expect, accept and handle the block or ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Ruby method also takes an implicit block argument which is not needed in the signature. If you study `create_table`'s method body, you'll find this: `yield td if block_given?`

This means: If there's a block given (or provided), call the implicit block using the `td` local variable as a block argument (which would be `t` in your example).

As long as you don't need to access the provided block directly, you don't need to have the block as a method argument. If you should need it, you'd declare it as a method argument, like this:

```
def create_table(table_name, comment: nil, **options, &block)
  # do something with block
end
```

Instead of having an implicit method block argumet and calling `yield td`, you could also have an explicit method block argument and call `block.call(td)` instead. The ruby implementation differs between those two, yielding will probably always be faster.

And you're right: `*args` is for splat arguments, where `args` will be an array of argument in the method body. `**kwargs` (or `**options` here) is for keyword arguments, where `kwargs` (or `options`) will be a hash of arguments in the method body.

Answer (score 2):

When you check the link, that you have added. You can read the explanation itself.

`**options` represents the `x` number of hashes, in this case you can specify `:id`, `:primary_key`, ....

Block is passed as an implicit part, not as an argument and will be executed using the `yield` keyword inside the method.
When examine `create_table` method you will see line of code

```
...
yield td if block_given?
#This part will execute the block that you pass
#If you pass any block to the method
...
```

[Passing blocks](http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html)

[yield](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/18-blocks/lessons/54-yield)

Also there are two ways of using the `t` argument. It represents the table itself, and you can call `column` method on it (which will create the column) or for example `string` method which will create a string column (a shorthand).

```
create_table(:suppliers) do |t|
  t.column :name, :string, limit: 60
  # Other fields here
end
```

Or

```
create_table(:suppliers) do |t|
  t.string :name, limit: 60
  # Other fields here
end
```

In both ways you are executing methods on the tableObject, and these methods will add columns to the table. If you do not pass the block, no columns will be create when the method is executed, but you can still add columns to the table, by executing `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements` methods

```
create_table(:suppliers)
# Add a column to 'suppliers'.
add_column(:suppliers, :name, :string, {limit: 60})
```